# How do i change the color of the text in a radio input field

Tags: javascript, html

Ok so I am making a test that has a list of questions that contains a list of answers. Im trying to make the test change the color of the users wrong answers to highlight red and have the correct answers highlighted green. I understand how to change the background color of elements. However i do not understand how to change the background color of the inner html of a input element of the radio type.  When i run this code i think its trying to change the actual radio input.  Any help is appreciated.

A sample for HTML test:

```
<ol>

<li ><p id = "question 1">What are the three main areas of the Standard User Interface?</p>
  <ul type="none">
    <li><input type="radio" name="q1" value="0"  /> Header, Banner, Frame, Application Window</li>
    <li><input type="radio" name="q1" value="0"  /> Content Frame, Homepage, Form </li>
    <li><input type="radio" name="q1" value="1"  /> Application Navigator, Banner Frame, Content Frame </li>
    <li><input type="radio" name="q1" value="0"  /> Larry, Moe, and Curly</li>
  </ul>
</li>

<li><p id = "question 2">In the  User interface, what is the gray toolbar called which allows you to add bookmarks?</p>

  <ul type="none">
    <li><input type="radio" name="q2" value="0" /> Gauge</li>
    <li><input type="radio" name="q2" value="1" /> Edge</li>
    <li><input type="radio" name="q2" value="0" /> Remedy</li>
    <li><input type="radio" name="q2" value="0" /> Banner</li>
  </ul>
</li>

<li><p id = "question 3">What can be captured in an update set?</p>

  <ul type="none">
    <li><input type="radio" name="q3" value="0" /> Modified CI Rules</li>
    <li><input type="radio" name="q3" value="1" /> Business Rules</li>
    <li><input type="radio" name="q3" value="0" /> Scheduled Jobs</li>
    <li><input type="radio" name="q3" value="0" /> None of these</li>
  </ul>
</li>

</ol>

<button id = "finish" onchange = "hide" onclick="finishTest()"> Submit Test  </button> <button id = "retry"  onclick="reloadPage()"> Try Again?</button>
```

My javascript Code:

```
function finishTest(){
//There are actually 37 questions on the test so far only included 3
var score = 0;
var totalQuestions = 37;


for(var questionNum = 1; questionNum<=totalQuestions; questionNum++) {
    var radios = document.getElementsByName('q'+questionNum);
    var uQuestion = document.getElementById("question "+questionNum).innerHTML;
    for (var i = 0, length = radios.length; i < length; i++) {
        if (radios[i].checked && radios[i].value=="1"){

            score++;
            alert(radios.innerHTML);
            radios.innerHTML.style.backgroundColor = "lawngreen";

            }else if (radios[i].checked && radios[i].value=="0"){


            alert(radios.innerHTML);
            radios.innerHTML.style.backgroundColor = "red";


            }
    }
}

score = parseFloat(score*100/totalQuestions).toFixed(1);
alert("You scored "+score+"%");

document.getElementById('finish').style.visibility='hidden';

}
```

Comment: There are a few conceptual problems there. The text is not the innerHTML of the radio, it is **part of** the inner HTML of the LI that the input is a child of -- as is the text. Second, the innerHTML property is not an object, it is a string value. It does not have a style property of its own. Third, you're referencing `radios.innerHTML.style` -- this is trying to change the style property of the innerHTML property of an array, which does not exist at all. `radios[i].parentNode.style.backgroundColor` might get you there.

Comment: So i should be trying to change the background color of the list item right?

Comment: Yes, both the radio and the text are children of the LI. Now, depending on how you are using CSS to lay out the text, it might wind up being better if you wrapped the text in another element, like a span. Also, if you put a label tag around both the input and the text, it will help your form be more usable because users can click the text to select the option, rather than trying to be a "mouse sniper" and having to click directly on the bullet.

Comment: Also, if you use classes as kasper suggests in his answer, you don't have to put inline css in your javascript -- good practice!

Comment: Sorry kind of new to HTML.I tried using your radios[i].parentNode.style.backgroundColor. It worked but can you explain to me how the parentNode of the radio input is the actualy text that changed color?

Comment: Sure! Thinking of an HTML element like a box, you've got the LI box opening. Inputs and images are a little different in that they aren't a box, or rather, they're a self-contained box. So you've got that input inside the LI box, next you've got some text just hanging out there. Everything is in a box, so even when you don't specify it, there's an explicit box called a TextNode which surrounds the words. Then, you close the li box `</li>`. So, the input and the TextNode are both "siblings", "children" of the "parent" LI. When you change styles of the parent box, it cascades to the children.

Comment: Ah ok so the list item is actually the parent of everything inside it. That makes a lot of sense thank you!

Comment: You got it! An important note (that you've surely noticed), not all style properties cascade the same way. For example, if you put a border on the parent, not every child is going to get a border as well -- it stays on the parent. For the most part, the text-related styles "trickle down" to the children, where box and background styles stick at the level they are applied. Check this out for more information on cascading: http://webdesignfromscratch.com/html-css/css-inheritance-cascade/

Comment: Typo that I can't edit out -- "explicit box" should be "implicit" :)

Comment: One more note! Please consider using the label. I've made a sample here so you can see the difference -- you have to give your inputs unique IDs, but try clicking the answer (click the text!) with a label vs. without a label. As you can see, it is much easier to use the form when you have a label wrapping both the input and the text: http://jsfiddle.net/vc9v2072/

Comment: I will go back and add labels it is more user friendly than sniping how you mention haha, Btw how do i pick your answer in the first comment

Comment: I didn't post an answer, these are just comments and they can't be picked as answers. The guys that posted answers are not wrong, they just didn't explain themselves very well, you could pick one of them :) chsdk seems tenacious, pick his hehe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The  best approach is to use two different classes `correct` and `wrong` and assign them to answers.

1. Define the style of two CSS classes `correct` and `wrong`:

   ```
   .correct {
       background-color : green;
   }

   .wrong {
       background-color : red;
   }
   ```
2. Then in your JavaScript, assign the corresponding classes for each answer (the corresponding `<li>` tag) :

   ```
   yourAnswer.className="correct"; or yourAnswer.className="wrong";
   ```

Where `yourAnswer` is the `<li>` of each selected answer.

**Note:** As suggested by  [Chris Baker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/610573/chris-baker) it would be better to put the `input` button and its corresponding `text` in a `label` together, it's more ***ergonomic*** as you can see in the first radio of the DEMO.

```
  <li>
    <label for="q1a">
        <input id="q1a" type="radio" name="q1" value="0"  /> Answer with a label
    </label>
  </li>
```

[**Here's a DEMO Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/4p6zr1nz/1/)

Comment: Your code contains an error that the OP also made: you cannot put styles or classes on `radios` because that is an array. He is iterating through the array, so `radios[i]` is the element, and where you'd add or remove classes.

Comment: I see you corrected it, I retracted my downvote. If you would add labels to the markup, this would be great advice :)

Comment: Thanks, but I haven't really understood your advice?

Comment: I am suggesting a way you could make your answer more complete, by advising he add labels to the form, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/vc9v2072/ -- try to select the first option by clicking the text, then the second. Any time you use a radio and some text, you should wrap them in a label to make it easier for the user. That isn't part of the question, but it could be part of a complete answer. Up to you :)

Comment: Ok Great, thanks I see it now, well pointed out, I'am Editing my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Just make two css classes "correct" and "wrong". Then assign these classes to the corresponding `li` elements.

[Jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/r23022sn/3/)

```
li.correct{

    color:green;
}
li.wrong{

    color:red;
}
```